# What is a RAP Number™?

Tags: pattern, number-property

Taking inspiration from "What is the word™" series, here the numbers conforms to a special rule, I call it a RAP number™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| RAP number™ | NOT RAP number™ |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 19 |
| 27 | 78 |
| 43 | 37 |
| 110 | 193 |
| 122 | 364 |
| 611 | 561 |
| 5132 | 5096 |
| 4703 | 7961 |
| 25117 | 25169 |
| 810221 | 71423 |

This is my first crack at this type of puzzle, so suggestions and edits are welcome.

I don't think the CSV is needed here, but for those who need it, here it is

```
RAP number™,  NOT RAP number™  
12,     19
27,     78
43,     37
110,    193
122,    364
611,    561
5132,   5096
4703,   7961
25117,  25169
810221, 71423
```

You can differentiate any number into these categories. This "Rule" can be applied to each and every number that ever existed; order does not matter.

**NOTE** I misprinted last number, it is supposed to be 810221

Comment: A good question :) Both the answers are great.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Does RAP stand for

> Reverse, Add, Palindrome?

Some examples:

> RAP numbers: 12+21 = 33, 611+116 = 727, 25117 + 71152 = 96269
>  NONRAP numbers: 19+91 = 110, 193+391 = 584, 5096+6905 = 12001

Comment: That's very good, but unfortunately, it doesn't work for the RAP number 81022 + 22018 = 103040. (It's the only one that doesn't fit, though.)

Comment: @MOehm Oh wow, you're right, I'm not sure how I missed that... my bad.

Comment: @smriti: Maybe, but I think it's more likely that it is just hard for others to see the rule. Authors often misjudge the difficulty of their puzzles.

Answer (score 17):

Possibly a RAP number may be one where the numbers are

> *R*ead *A*lphabetically *P*rogressing and are non-decreasing in order from left-to-right 
>  The description below needs to call the 0 digit the ten(s) digit - if acceptable?
>
>
>  12 = One Two
>  43 = Four Three
>  110 = One One Tens
>  122 = One Two Two
>  5132 = Five One Three Two
>  4703 = Four Seven Tens Three
>  81022 = Eight One Tens Two Two
>
>
>   And all the non-RAP words' digits are not in alphabetical order.

Comment: Whoa, That is one mind blowing answer!!(I wish I can give more than 1 upvote) But unfortunately it is not correct, even I did not notice this..... 27 is also RAP number and 78 is not RAP number, I will add some more examples

Comment: @smriti you may want to consider offering a small bounty for this answer. There is an option of "one of the answers is exemplary, and worthy of an additional bounty", where it is clear that your intentions are to award one of the existing answerers (and not prospective ones).

Comment: @smriti Ahh.. I thought 78 *is* a RAP number.

Comment: @Matsmath I don't no how to do that, thanks for suggestion, I will look it up, and add(still, I have to wait for 17 hours)

Comment: Thanks Matsmath and Smriti for looking at this. I hope this post be fine without a bounty. It needed a workaround for zero and didn't crack the puzzle because of this.

Comment: It's amazing how an answer can be wrong, and yet so overwhelmingly convincing...

Comment: What if you called 0 `ought`?

Comment: Thank you very much smriti for your bountifulness. I hope someone will find the real answer to this nice extension from "What is the word™"  to "What is the number™" - I'm still puzzling on it!